# Can't Change URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am very much a noob at sharepoint, so this is probably an easy one. I am trying to get SharePoint 2013 up and running. When I go through the config wizard, it creates a site for me with a URL that starts with `http://servername`. This is NOT what I want. I want the URL to being `http://FQDN` since that is how people will actually be accessing it, and I want it on port 80. SharePoint is fighting me tooth and nail on this.

I have no data to preserve. This is a vm with a snapshot pre SP install, so I can easily blow away everything I have and start again. And I have. A couple of times. What I am looking for the easiest way to get what I want.

I would welcome any and all input.

Answer (score 3):

Go into Central Administration and look for Alternate Access Mappings, probably under Server Settings.  From there, select your web application in the selector.  Edit the public URLs and enter your desired URL as the default zone.

Note: if you have tried to change the URL directly in IIS, then you may have to make the change there as well.

I haven't done this in SP2013 but it should be the same as past versions, though the AAM link might be in a different location.

Comment: I believe that's what I did the first time, but after the change, the site started prompting me for a username and password which failed no matter what I used. Regardless, I will try this again as I have nothing to lose. I will let you know how it pans out.

Comment: That is more likely due to IE settings.  Make sure the domain you are trying to access is listed in IE as in the Intranet zone

Comment: Ok, I reinstalled and reconfigured. Once again, after I changed the access mapping, IE started prompting me for credentials. I have added the site to the Trusted Sites zone. WTF? I have now spent several days on this one issue.

Comment: Add it to the Intranet Zone, not the Trusted sites.  Not sure why but Trusted Sites doesn't pass credentials

Comment: Also- are you attempting to access the site from the server itself?  If so, there is what is known as  a "loop back" issue that causes this exact behavior. Method 2 on here seems to work well:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861